# How do you work with Asynchronous functions, recursively?

Tags: recursion, async

I am currently working on FLEX and have to call a web services. once I have the result, I have to call the web service again, with the previous result as the input.

A compounding problem, is that the service might return multiple results, and I have to call the service again with each of the results as the input. Lastly, i need the results to be in a hierarchical array collection, with each result as the child of the input to the web service.

If it were a synchronous function, it would have been very easy, but I have spent half a day trying to come up with something elegant for the web service.

I ended up with having two arrays, one for the input, and one for the results. Every time I had one or more result, I would put it in the Input array and the results. I would then remove the first item from the input array and call the web service with it, and so on, till I finished all the inputs. Once I had all the results, I made a recursive function that would create the hierarchical tree, that I needed.

This seems like a very hacky, WTF Solution. Is there any elegant and better solution? I am all ears.

Comment: If this question seems to be better suited for stackoverflow, mods, please migrate it there.

Comment: It's not a Stack Overflow question - primarily because there's no code! Design and algorithm questions are definitely on topic here.

Comment: Maybe some kind of Queueing setup would help?

Comment: @Daenyth The input and result arrays that I mentioned, are a form of a queue. Or am I missing something, and you are talking of something else?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: I was talking more about using some kind of library to manage it rather than doing it by hand - such a library may have some kind of provisions for a situation like yours

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe, sounds like a decent approach to me, though I might look at implementing the pending calls as a stack instead of an array, first for cleaner popping, second because it probably works better with filling out your tree. FIlling out your tree as you go, along with maintaining some kind of pointer to the current location in it might be cleaner still. Your query function can go to the bookmark, query with that, add the results, and move the bookmark to the first child.  If no children, move it to a sibling, or go up the tree looking for unexplored branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could implement some sort of "auto-loading tree".

Start with the first node. This node fetches data from server. For each item found  in the response, it creates a child node that will load the appropriate data. And so on...

One thing you need to know is "When is it complete ?"

This can be handled with events. Each node send an event up when all its children are complete. Recursively this will end up telling the root that all is children are complete. The root node will fire the "I'm complete" event to tell whoever wants to know it, that the tree is complete.

However, I'm wondering : why don't you create a service on the server that returns the whole tree ?

Comment: The webservice I am consuming, is the public API of a well known web site. If I can call it recursively, It would be possible for my App to have no server side code, since all my code would run in the user's flash client.

Comment: Based on how it's set up, events aren't even necessarily needed for completion-testing.  Each node can increment an internal counter when it starts its children, and the child nodes that do the AJAX call to populate themselves can have a callback to the parent.  Upon AJAX completion, the child node uses the callback, which decrements the parent's internal counter, and if it hits zero, the parent does the same for its own parent, all the way up the line.

Comment: @Izkata : Devdatta is using Flex. In Flex, it is common practice to use events instead of callbacks.

Comment: Hm, didn't know that (never used Flex and was thinking more generally).  Alrighty then

Answer (score 1):

I also have a series of web based services which need to be called in order.  I solved the issue with AJAX.  The key is having a callback mechanism to perform the recursion, forcing synchronization.

Something like this ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/))

```
function Recurse(params)
{
$.get(url,
            {params},
            function (data) {Recurse(data)}//callback does recursive call, also passes in variable data received from the web service
            ,'html');
}
```

You should check the API in question to see if it is a tree data structure like the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Usually recursion is a good approach to iterate trees.  If it's just a flat, linear API then a Queue/Stack can be used to push/pop your way through the API recursively.

Here's how to recursively iterate the DOM.  Code for another Tree based API structure will be similar (javascript)

```
function walk(node, func) {
   //walk the height of the tree
   func(node);//do something to the node
   node = node.firstChild;
   while(node) {
      //walk siblings
      walk(node, func);
      node = node.nextSibling;
   }
}
```